# Odd URL's appearing in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

We have noticed within the past few months these odd URL's showing up in our Google Analytics account and don't know how they are being generated. After the end of a normal page URL we get these alpha-numeric paths created:

```
example.com/about/AsqQilWRpZ2
example.com/about/FfjLIuytp4c
example.com/about/YjJiLWRpZ2
```

The site is Wordpress based and using many plugins. Could this be a hack or a bot causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's most likely bot/spam traffic**. To find out, you should look further into your data:

- **Referral information:** on your site content report, add `Full Referrer` as a secondary dimension and see where traffic is coming from. If it's `(Direct)` it's most likely spam. If it comes up with an actual traffic source (a page on your website or a page on another website), fix those pages to get rid of the bad links.

[image]

- **Country/SIP**: you can repeat the above exercise but change the secondary dimension to `Country` or `Network Domain` and see if odd patterns come up (eg traffic from Russia and China if your website caters for the US would be suspect).

---

**If it's spam, your solutions are:**

- **Enable the bot filtering option**: go to the view settings and check the option

[image]

- **Create country filters:** if you're getting traffic (spam or not) from countries you really don't care about (eg if your website is about local bread delivery in the US and you're getting traffic from India or Ukraine), then simple create view filters to exclude traffic from those countries: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033162?hl=en
- **Update robots.txt**: this is less likely to work, but you could try updating your robots.txt to specifically exclude certain areas of your website from crawling if the spam you're getting is focusing on certain content areas, and which bots/spiders are crawling you may or may not (most likely won't) listen to the robots.txt and stop.